# Location and Google maps in android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

i am working on Locations and Google maps and i came across this link --> [GSM-Tracker](https://cellphonetrackers.org/gsm/gsm-tracker.php)

Following this link i retrieved MNC, MCC, LAC and CID values of my mobile...but now i need to know whats the logic or a code behind the button TRACK IT (in this link) that it directly gives me my location...

mine is an android app so what piece of code should i write..that my button leads me to google maps showing me my exact location

OR any idea how to transform this php code in android ????

Comment: View page source and the "logic" you are looking for is at the top of page source in function `Cell()`. This website is in PHP, so there will be so many difference when writing for android.

Comment: okay....but what if i want the same thing to be in my app...exactly this kind of thing....then how would i do it ?

Comment: @ShahbazTalpur any idea how to transform this php code into android ??

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options in order to retrieve the location of a device.

1. [Fused location api](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)
2. Location manager api

There is a whole free [course](https://www.udacity.com/course/google-location-services-on-android--ud876-1) by Udacity about google location services.
What I suggest is that you should use the fused location as it is more optimal for the battery. For implementation see the links.

Comment: But that will give the location of user? In question there is a example of website where you put some values/codes and get location of some cell tower I guess. Sorry if I am mistaken.

Comment: For sure my answer is not what you are looking for. You need a database with pairs of LACs to Lat-Lon and then just display them on a map. The problem in your solution is where to find such database. Is there a free api or ready db?

Comment: @toshkinl can u plz give me an overview about fused location api link....will it give the current location of device?